# impossible reach items list with REST API in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

i've a problem with a REST API call.

i can reach the list without problems, as you can see in the image that follows  [image]
but the problem come when i try to reach the list items [image]
i looked around but i didn't find a solution and i cannot understand why the same call working as well with other lists and not in this one.

this list is a custom list from template, maybe it has something to do with it?

Comment: Does this list is created using custom list template saved from another existing list? Also try adding select clause `items?$select=ID,Title`

Comment: @GaneshSanap wow it's works! thank you so much ! add this as answer so i can accept it

Comment: Welcome. Please accept and upvote if this answer helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `select` clause in your REST url and try fetching the items:

Use url something like below:

```
/items?$select=ID,Title
```